# Trackpad is not working on Lenovo Yoga 370

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad

On my Lenovo Yoga 370, the mouse arrow blinks when I move with an external mouse. If I stop moving the mouse the mouse pointer disappears. I got a new symbol by my clock. it is a faded circle with an mouse symbol in it. If I mouse over text it becomes a I bar. If I mouse over a link it becomes a hand.

I reinstalled the drivers and rebooted. The trackpad appears to be enabled in windows. The track point on the keyboard works. An extremal mouse works. Trackpad does not click or move the mouse when touched.

Comment: Sorry to hear about this, but you are providing little to no information that anyone can use to help you. What is the make and model of the laptop you are using? Can you use an external mouse? Did this just suddenly started happening? Or did something cause this? Like dropping the laptop or spilling something on it?

Comment: It just started happening. it is a Lenovo yoga 370. It was not dropped and no water damage. I can use an extremal mouse.